# Error inflating class fragment, cannot start the activity, My app starts and stops abruptly

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am new to android, I have been following the lessons by edx. But when I tried to run the code, I am getting the stack trace as,

```
12 11:47:44.436 2965-2965/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: com.example.lambda.momaer, PID: 2965
                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.lambda.momaer/com.example.lambda.momaer.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2660)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2730)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:185)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1567)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5847)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1010)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
                                                  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:769)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:812)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:923)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:808)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:923)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:808)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:510)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:420)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:371)
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292)
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                     at com.example.deepakchethan.moviemanager.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6117)
                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2613)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2730) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:185) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1567) 
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5847) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1010) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805) 
                                                  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                     at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
                                                     at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:362)
                                                     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
                                                     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                                                     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.isSupportFragmentClass(Fragment.java:464)
                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:3404)
                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:120)
                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:378)
                                                     at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:33)
                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:79)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:739)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:812) 
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:923) 
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:808) 
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:923) 
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:808) 
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:510) 
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:420) 
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:371) 
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292) 
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                     at com.example.deepakchethan.moviemanager.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25) 
                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6117) 
                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2613) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2730) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:185) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1567) 
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5847) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1010) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
```

And the Main activity looks like,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        Class frag;
        if (id == R.id.nav_upComing) {
            frag=upComingFragment.class;
            showFragment(frag);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_nowPlaying) {
            frag=nowPlayingFragment.class;
            showFragment(frag);
        } else if  (id == R.id.nav_close) {
            finish();
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    private void showFragment(Class frag) {
        Fragment fragment=null;

        try {
            fragment= (Fragment) frag.newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        FragmentManager fm=getSupportFragmentManager();
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flip,fragment,null).commit();
    }
}
```

My xml files looks like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.deepakchethan.moviemanager.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/flip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></fragment>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I searched and found no solution on stackoverflow. I just thought i will ask myself. Please help me.

Comment: in the xml you need to specify the class of your fragment

Comment: The same error even after specifying the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has already been answered several times, **you cannot change a statically created fragment**. So change the tag from `fragment` to `FrameLayout` in your xml file. It should work fine.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.deepakchethan.moviemanager.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/flip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></FrameLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```